# Dope sheet and graph editor are kind of "dark"

Tags: graph-editor, dopesheet

This strange thing happens when some books falls on my keyboard. It doesn't affect to my workflow at all but it's really annoying. [image: Screenshoot of the interface with the "lights off"]

As you can see, it's seems like i have switch off a bright option or something. I can't explain this very good and neither know how to search for a solution.
This only happens on that project. I've tried reseting blender and opening other projects but they looks cool.[image: dope sheet of other project on the same blender version]

Anyone knows the shortcut or the key i missclick or it's other kind of problem?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use "Alt+P" to clear the preview range.